# What are the rules for valid keys in ebextensions files?

Tags: yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to run java 11 on an elastic beanstalk environment. I found [Java 11 on AWS beanstalk for Spring boot project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088465/java-11-on-aws-beanstalk-for-spring-boot-project) which looks like what I want.

When I create the config file like in that question I get

Error processing file (Skipping): '.ebextensions/10_Java.config' - Contains invalid key: '200-download-rpm-package'. For information about valid keys, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

My yaml file is a copy of the one in the answer to the question above.

```
container_commands:
100-remove-old-java-ajb:
    command: "sudo yum remove -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless"
200-download-rpm-package:
    command: "wget https://d3pxv6yz143wms.cloudfront.net/11.0.4.11.1/java-11-amazon-corretto-devel-11.0.4.11-1.x86_64.rpm "
300-install-java-ajb:
    command: "sudo yum localinstall -y java-11-amazon-corretto-devel-11.0.4.11-1.x86_64.rpm"
```

But when I look in the doc page linked, there nothing about the naming rules for labels that I might be violating. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: can you share contents of that 10_Java.config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were formating issues in the original response (related to specifics of Stackoverflow editor). I've updated it.
Also posting formatter version here.

```
container_commands:
    100-remove-old-java:
        command: "sudo yum remove -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless"
    200-download-rpm-package:
        command: "wget https://d3pxv6yz143wms.cloudfront.net/11.0.4.11.1/java-11-amazon-corretto-devel-11.0.4.11-1.x86_64.rpm "
    300-install-java:
        command: "sudo yum localinstall -y java-11-amazon-corretto-devel-11.0.4.11-1.x86_64.rpm"
```

Comment: I will never copy and paste yaml code without checking its structure again! Thank you.