# Can I use java11 with elastic beanstalk and tomcat?

Tags: java, scala, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a scala application that uses scala 2.11 and Java 11 and runs in tomcat . I had to move to Java 11 from Java 8 due to some dependency issues.

In the past I ran this app on elastic beanstalk (back when the app used to run on java 8). However it doesn't look like there's an elastic beanstalk platform for java 11. Do I need to find a new way to deploy and run my app or is there a simple way to get elastic beanstalk to run java11?

Ive tried using the ebextensions approach described at [Java 11 on AWS beanstalk for Spring boot project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088465/java-11-on-aws-beanstalk-for-spring-boot-project) but its not working, and it seems like its working around a problem with elastic beanstalk being stuck in the past. I feel like its time to forget elastic beaanstalk but its worked well up til now so I'm reluctant to do so without a clear alternative.

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.java the latest elastic beanstalk platform offered is java 8 with tomcat 8.5 
According to the docs, the latest tomcat version for Elastic Beanstalk is

Platform Version and Solution Stack Name

Java 8 with Tomcat 8.5 version 3.3.4

64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v3.3.4 running Tomcat 8.5 Java 8

2018.03.0

Java 1.8.0_242

3.1.0

Tomcat 8.5.51

Apache 2.4.41 (default), Apache 2.2.34, Nginx 1.16.1

Comment: Did you find any solution to this question?